# How do I output % similarity on the y axis of my dendogram?

Tags: r

I'm trying to replace the height axis on my dendogram with % similarity. My current code is:

```
ABf.x<-as.matrix(ABflip)
hc<-hclust(dist(ABf.x),method="ward")
plot(hc,hang=-1,labels=ABf.x[,1])
plot(hc,main="", hang=-1,ylab="Similarity",axes=FALSE,labels=ABf.x[,1])

scale=seq(0,max(hc$height),by=10)

sequence<-as.integer(seq(1,max(hc$height)),by=10)
percent<-as.integer((sequence/max(hc$height)*100))

lines(x = c(0,0), y = c(0,max(hc$height)),type = "n")

axis(2,at=scale, labels=percent)
```

the plot current comes out without a scale giving the error:

> Error in axis(2, at = scale, labels = percent) : 
>         'at' and 'labels' lengths differ, 36 != 351

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the iris dataset as example data. You could play with the scale to get it to top out at 100 instead of 99

```
ABf.x<-as.matrix(iris)
hc<-hclust(dist(ABf.x),method="ward")
plot(hc,hang=-1,labels=ABf.x[,1])

plot(hc,main="", hang=-1,ylab="Similarity",axes=FALSE,labels=ABf.x[,1])

scale=seq(0, max(hc$height), by=10)
sequence<-as.integer(seq(1,(max(hc$height)), by=10)) #get sequence of heights from dendrogram
percent<-as.integer((sequence/max(hc$height)*100)) #Convert these to a percent of the maximum height

lines(x = c(0,0), y = c(0,max(hc$height)),type = "n")
axis(2,at=scale, labels=percent)
```

Link to result: [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jegFs.jpg)

Comment: Thanks for your comment and I think that is part of the answer for sure. In my data the height maxes out at 351. When I alter the scale I get it on a 0-100 scale but it scrunches the axis down. I'm going to post a picture to the question as an example, please reference that to get an idea of the issue I'm trying to fix now,

Comment: Did you try the code I suggested? It should fix the scrunching issue. The "at" parameter in the axis(2,at=scale, labels=percent) line places the new axis (the percent) along the range of the scale (defined as 0 to max(hc$height)).

Comment: Whoops I hadn't noticed the change to those lines! adding those changes did fix the scrunching issue, but now I also get the error output:
    Error in axis(2, at = scale, labels = percent) : 
  'at' and 'labels' lengths differ, 36 != 351

Comment: Could you provide the code that you're using? The code I provided does not have that error, so I think you may be missing a line somewhere.

Comment: not sure what I missed but I retyped the whole thing and it works perfectly now! thanks!!!!